# ASCII array to number In Python

Tags: python, ascii

I am trying to parse an array of ascii characters which form a number (float, int...) Sometimes array length is 1, 2, 3....8... I am looking for a way to get the whole array (with just one complete value each time) and return the number to add it to a json.

I am using python 3. Is there a fixed function to do that? I haven't found anything on the internet yet.

I was thinking in something like this:

```
return arrayBytes[0]<<8 | arrayBytes[1]
```

But I get values like 574 in a % value so it has to be wrong and just would work with 2 ascii array length.

Here you have an example of the input:

```
4 value: 0x32 0x38 0x2e 0x36
2 value 0x34 0x39 
3 value 0x30 0x2e 0x34
```

Comment: Show us a sample of the input.

Comment: 4 value: 0x32 0x38 0x2e 0x36, 2 value 0x34 0x39, 3 value 0x30 0x2e 0x34

Comment: `0x32 0x38 0x2e 0x36` is `28.6` as ASCII; are you sure these are not just numbers already?

Comment: How do you know how many bytes to read?

Comment: They are numbers. I need to rejoin to get the 28.6 you printed

Comment: @Biribu: are you formatting these or are they the literal `0`, `x`, `3`, `2` ASCII characters with spaces in between?

Comment: I get in each array position 32, not 0x

Comment: @Biribu: can you show us the output of `repr(array)` then? It is unclear as to what datatype you have here.

Comment: I get this in a 4 position array: [4, 50, 56, 46] It is supposed to be temperature

Comment: It was wrong, this a temperature ok: 50, 57, 46, 57

Comment: @Biribu: so you have *integers*?

Comment: @Biribu: is this Python 2 or Python 3?

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have ASCII representations of numbers:

```
>>> '\x32\x38\x2e\x36'
'28.6'
>>> '\x34\x39'
'49'
>>> '\x30\x2e\x34'
'0.4'
```

Calling `float()` on these to turn them into Python float objects is enough:

```
>>> float('\x32\x38\x2e\x36')
28.6
>>> float('\x34\x39')
49.0
>>> float('\x30\x2e\x34')
0.4
```

If your input is integers, then they represent ASCII codepoints. In Python 3, use `bytes()` to quickly turn those back to text:

```
>>> bytes([50, 57, 46, 57])
b'29.9'
>>> bytes([50, 57, 46, 57]).decode('ascii')
'29.9'
>>> float(bytes([50, 57, 46, 57]))
29.9
```

In Python 2, use `bytearray()` instead:

```
>>> bytearray([50, 57, 46, 57])
bytearray(b'29.9')
>>> str(bytearray([50, 57, 46, 57]))
'29.9'
>>> bytearray([50, 57, 46, 57]).decode('ascii')
u'29.9'
>>> float(bytearray([50, 57, 46, 57]))
29.9
```

Either way you can go from list of integers to bytes, text or a floating point value with ease.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to use bitwise operations because those only work with small python integers. Instead you will need to multiply by the equivalent power of two.

```
mult = 1 << 8
answer = 0
for number in asciiBytes:
    answer *= mult
    answer += number
```

If you are just storing a string representation of the number, and not storing the number as the bitwise pieces separated, then call `float(str)` to turn the string into a number.

For example `float('423.3') == 423.3`